# Raspberry Pi: mvoe home & var folders to USB HDD?

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, raspberry-pi, debian-wheezy, mysql5

I have a Raspberry Pi running raspian.  I've installed Apache2, PHP & MySQL.  Apache & MySQL are both configured to use sub-directories of /var.  I'd like to use a directory on my USB HDD instead of my SD card.

I'd also like to move the /home directory to the USB HDD.

I'd like to avoid re-partioning my HDD if possible.  I thought maybe I could use a symlink to tell raspian that /var is really at /media/USBHDD1/var and /home is really at /media/USBHDD1/home.  I tried it last night but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You should be able to move the home directories to the flash drive and then mount the drive to /home in `fstab`.  So your `fstab` would look like: `/dev/sdX# /home ext4 defaults 0 0` (replace X# with your device id/partition num and defaults with your preferred).  That would be automatic each boot.

Comment: That looks like it needs a separate partition.  I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Not sure why you say that, you could mount the whole disc there.  And if it supports the formatting, you really shouldn't have much trouble.  When I get home later - if I remember I will try to set that up - because there is no real reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Right now, I have something like the following in. Y fstab (typed from memory):  /dev/sda1 /media/USBHDD1  auto defaults 0 0    I'd like to avoid creating a new partition if I can do so.  I'd like to mount /media/USBHDD1/home as /home.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You need a block device, so a partition or full drive.  If you do the whole drive mounted, you could accomplish the goal with symlinks to get the specifics.

Comment: But the question is HOW to symlink the folders.  Like I said in my OP, I thought maybe I could use a simlink but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong before, but I just tried to create the symlink and it worked this time.  Thanks at least you confirmed that symlink would work.